# Missing MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I'm trying to modify calendar permissions using Exchange Management Shell on Exchange Server 2010. But - I don't see cmdlet Set/Get/Add-MailboxFolderPermission (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff522363.aspx) among cmdlets - if I list all exchange-related cmdlets (get-excommand), I see e.g. these:

```
...
Function        Set-MailboxDatabase                                 ...
Function        Set-MailboxDatabaseCopy                             ...
Function        Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration                   ...
Function        Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration                     ...
...
```

There isn't Set-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet.

Question is - what am I missing here? For the record, I wanted to follow this guide: http://thoughtsofanidlemind.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/calendar-sharing-owa-2010/ and it's RTM version, not SP1.

Thank you!

Comment: To be more specific - cmdlets Get-MailboxFolderPermission and Add-MailboxFolderPermission DO work, but Set- doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally figured that out. Set-MailboxFolderPermission appears newly in SP1. For RTM version, the solution is in Remove-MailboxFolderPermission and then re-assign the permissions with Add-MailboxFolderPermission.